# move selection to a separate file

Tags: vim

With vim, how can I move a piece of text to a new file? For the moment, I do this:

- select the text
- use `:w new_file`
- select the text again
- delete the text

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

### Before

a.txt

```
sometext
some other text
some other other text
end
```

### After

a.txt

```
sometext
end
```

b.txt

```
some other text
some other other text
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/7720520/14555505

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about these custom commands:

```
:command! -bang -range -nargs=1 -complete=file MoveWrite  <line1>,<line2>write<bang> <args> | <line1>,<line2>delete _
:command! -bang -range -nargs=1 -complete=file MoveAppend <line1>,<line2>write<bang> >> <args> | <line1>,<line2>delete _
```

Comment: This is very ugly, but hey, it seems to do in one step exactly what I asked for (I tried). +1, and accepted. I was looking for a native way to do this quickly but since there does not seem to be one, yours will do just fine. Thanks!

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder. I find this pretty elegant; you only need to type it once (into your .vimrc).

Comment: You're right, "very ugly" shoud have been "very unfamiliar". Your command is very handy, and I think I definitely going to carve it in my .vimrc

Answer (score 13):

By "move a piece of text to a new file" I assume you mean cut that piece of text from the current file and create a new file containing only that text.

Various examples:

- `:1,1 w new_file` to create a new file containing only the text from line number 1
- `:5,50 w newfile` to create a new file containing the text from line 5 to line 50
- `:'a,'b w newfile` to create a new file containing the text from mark `a` to mark `b`

  - set your marks by using <kbd>ma</kbd> and <kbd>mb</kbd> where ever you like

The above only copies the text and creates a new file containing that text. You will then need to delete afterward.

This can be done using the same range and the `d` command:

- `:5,50 d` to delete the text from line 5 to line 50
- `:'a,'b d` to delete the text from mark `a` to mark `b`

Or by using <kbd>dd</kbd> for the single line case.

If you instead select the text using visual mode, and then hit `:` while the text is selected, you will see the following on the command line:

`:'<,'>`

Which indicates the selected text. You can then expand the command to:

`:'<,'>w >> old_file`

Which will **append** the text to an existing file. Then delete as above.

---

### One liner:

`:2,3 d | new +put! "`

The breakdown:

- `:2,3 d` - delete lines 2 through 3
- `|` - technically this redirects the output of the first command to the second command but since the first command doesn't output anything, we're just chaining the commands together
- `new` - opens a new buffer
- `+put! "` - put the contents of the unnamed register (`"`) into the buffer

  - The bang (`!`) is there so that the contents are put *before* the current line. This causes and empty line at the end of the file. Without it, there is an empty line at the top of the file.

Comment: Your assumption is right. This looks good, I'm going to test. Could you explain 2. a bit more? I'm not very familiar with ranges. EDIT: If I try this on the second line, it writes the first line to the other file, not the second line.

Comment: @greg0ire I got that a bit backward, I'll edit to better explain

Comment: I added an example to make my question clearer.

Comment: @greg0ire I corrected my answer. It's still two steps. The first copies and writes. The second deletes.

Comment: Ok, if I understand well, the trick is to use ranges to select and write in the same command. That's very similar to what I did. +1 for the detailed explanation, but I don't think this is more efficient, since the trick with hitting ':' is what I do for the moment.

Comment: @greg0ire Added a one line solution

Comment: Not really a one line solution, since both file still need to be written afterwards, but it is very nice!

Comment: Nice solution! You could also write it as `'<,'>d | new | 0put "` for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @embedded.kyle's answer and [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9160701/461834), I ended up with this one liner to append a selection to a file and delete from current file. After selecting some lines with `Shift+V`, hit `:` and run:

```
'<,'>w >> test | normal gvd
```

The first part appends selected lines. The second command enters normal mode and runs `gvd` to select the last selection and then deletes.

Answer (score 0):

Select the text in visual mode, then press <kbd>y</kbd> to "yank" it into the buffer (copy) or <kbd>d</kbd> to "delete" it into the buffer (cut).

Then you can `:split <new file name>` to split your vim window up, and press <kbd>p</kbd> to paste in the yanked text. Write the file as normal.

To close the split again, pass the split you want to close `:q`.

Comment: I have 4 steps for the moment: select, write, select, delete. With your method, I have 6 steps: select, delete, split, paste, write, close. I asked for something more efficient :P

Comment: Well, if you pass the split `:x` instead, you can combine writing and closing into one and make it five steps. :P

Comment: That's better, but 5 still > 4 :P

Answer (score 0):

Having the lines selected, the following works for me

```
:'<,'>w b.txt | '<,'>d
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).